# Specify empty argument with sbt 'run-main MainClass args'

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to run a main class with `sbt 'run-main'`.  However, I can't figure out how to specify an empty argument.

```
sbt 'run-main path.to.MainClass arg1 arg2 EMPTY_ARG3'
```

Quotes get interpreted literally.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For want of anything better, you could have a separate runner class than will replace a string of your choice with an empty argument, and run that from sbt instead.

```
object MainClassRunner {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val as = args map { case "EMPTY_ARG" => "" case x => x }
    path.to.MainClass.main(as)
  }
}
```